# Set Record Count before $this->setCollection($collection);

Tags: php, magento, report, magento-1.9

How we can set count of collection size before setting for the grid.

**Main Sales collection:**

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
           
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>$fromDate))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' =>$toDate))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq'=>Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
```

**Had join on that Collection:**

```
$Table = Mage::getModel('amorderattr/attribute')->getResource()->getTable('amorderattr/order_attribute');
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('custom_attributes' => $amastyTable), 'main_table.entity_id = custom_attributes.order_id',array('is_first_order'));
```

**Another Collection loaded:**

```
$CustomersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
        $newCustomersCollection = $CustomersCollection
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));
        if(strlen($storeId)==1)
            $newCustomersCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId()));
        else if($storeArr){
            $newCustomersCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeArr[0])->getWebsiteId()));
        }
        $newCustomers = count($newCustomersCollection);
```

**time periods:**

```
$frm = date("d M Y", strtotime($filterData->getData('from')));
        $to = date("d M Y", strtotime($filterData->getData('to')));
        $period=(string)$frm." - ". (string)$to;
```

**Another Collection:**

```
$totalAccountsCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
        if(strlen($storeId)==1)
            $totalAccountsCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId()));
        else if($storeArr){
            $totalAccountsCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeArr[0])->getWebsiteId()));
        }
        $totalAccounts=count($totalAccountsCollection);
```

**Again different collection Loaded:**

```
$CustomersCollection1 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));;
        $i=0;
        foreach ($CustomersCollection1->getData() as $customer) {
            $salesOrderCollection2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customer['entity_id']));
            if(!count($salesOrderCollection2->getData())) {
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $customer_having_account_but_no_order = $i;
```

**Again some other Info loaded:**

```
/* Total Customer Of USD Website starts */

        $USDCustomersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
        $USDCustomersCollection
            ->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));;
        $USDAccounts=count($USDCustomersCollection->getData());

        /* Total Customer Of USD Website ends */

        /* Total Customer Of EURO Website starts */

        $EUROCustomersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
        $EUROCustomersCollection
            ->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>2))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));;
        $EUROAccounts=count($EUROCustomersCollection->getData());

        /* Total Customer Of EURO Website starts */
```

**And Finally selecting Columns from it:**

```
$collection->getSelect()
            ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns('COUNT(*) as total_orders')
            ->columns('SUM(custom_attributes.is_first_order) as first_order')
            ->columns('SUM(main_table.customer_is_guest) as is_guest')
            ->columns('COUNT(*) - (SUM(main_table.customer_is_guest) + SUM(custom_attributes.is_first_order)) as returning_accounts');

        $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('new_accounts_created' => new Zend_Db_Expr($newCustomers)))
                                 ->columns(array('period' => new Zend_Db_Expr("'".$period."'")))
                                 ->columns(array('customer_having_account_but_no_order' => new Zend_Db_Expr($customer_having_account_but_no_order)))
                                 ->columns(array('usd_customer_account' => new Zend_Db_Expr($USDAccounts)))
                                 ->columns(array('euro_customer_account' => new Zend_Db_Expr($EUROAccounts)))
                                ->columns(array('total_accounts' => new Zend_Db_Expr($totalAccounts)));
```

**And Lastly setting my collection in prepareCollection:**

```
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

I have to to optimize it and at final setting collection to  $this->setCollection() this method it is taking 25 count as result but i get only one row in out put .

Therefore my pagination in of grid showing 25 records instead of 1(row which is getting)

[image: Check refernce image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I need to edit one of your core file. As it’s not a good practice to edit core file, I had overridden the core file.
Overriding LIB module

Copied Db.php file from magento / lib / Varien / Data / Collection / Db.php
Pasted it to local directory so the resultant folder structure would look like this:
magento / app / code / local / Varien / Data / Collection / Db.php

I have tried with so many ways
Finally I used getSelectCountSql() as well as getSize()